# Where should version independent python library go?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, version

I have a pure python module that will work for both Python 2.6 and 2.7.  Instead of putting the module into the python version specific paths, is it possible to place the library at one location that will be accessed by both Python 2.6 and 2.7?  System is Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you developing the module, or just want to install it?

Comment: I am the writer of the module.  Now I'm wondering how I can deploy it on new machines so that I don't have to worry about placing in in the appropriate python path (based on the default python version).

Comment: If you use [`distutils`](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/index.html) the normal way, _you_ don't have to worry about where the files must go. (Though the users must install your module separately for every Python version they use)

Answer (score 3):

You can install the library in one location like `/opt` and then create two soft links inside `/usr/lib/python2.6` and `/usr/lib/python2.7` pointing to that library.

Comment: The symlinks make a lot of sense, but I was just wondering if I could avoid having to touch the python version specific paths (even if it's just to create a symlink).

Answer (score 1):

By default, python26 searches for modules in */python2.6/* folders, while python27 looks in */python2.7/* folders.

One way to achieve your goal would be to add to system path another (common) location, by altering PYTHONPATH system variable:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/common/location
```